# send HTTP GET to each unicorn worker after heroku deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, unicorn

I'm wondering if anyone has ever looked into the idea of "warming up" their dynos and unicorn workers after a deploy/config change etc...

I have an app on heroku and i'm using preboot to help keep the site responsive during deploys but the first requests to each unicorn worker are always a bit slower then subsequent ones.

I was thinking you could run something on after_fork in unicorn config to send a request to the new worker.  But not sure exactly how to do it and it would be great if someone who has already solved this could share!

Thanks!
Duncan

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking into this.  The solution I came up with is to add:

```
ActionController::Integration::Session.new(::Rails.application).get '/'
```

to `after_fork` in `unicorn.rb`

As far as I understand it this will construct a local rack call to the root path which should warm up anything just like the first real request would.

I have not done extensive testing of this solution yet but will comment if I run into problems.